# EF Core - Double key with many to many relationship

Tags: c#, many-to-many, ef-core-2.2

#### Project environment

- EF Core 2.2.6
- Many-to-Many, indirect via join table
- Course records already exist on the database

As soon as I try to add a record to the join table, I get the following error message.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '3945' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

#### Entites, Join Table

```cs
public class Course
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // Filled with reference object and Id of the reference object
    public ICollection<UserCourse> CourseUsers { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserCourse> UserCourses { get; set; }
}

public class UserCourse
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public long CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

#### Fluent API

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
        .HasKey(uc => new { uc.UserId, uc.CourseId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
        .HasOne(uc => uc.Course)
        .WithMany(c => c.Users)
        .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.CourseId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserCourse>()
        .HasOne(uc => uc.User)
        .WithMany(c => c.Courses)
        .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
}
```

#### Considerations

The record of the course with the ID `3945` already exists in the database and this probably causes the error message. I don't know how to make EF create only the relationship in the join table and not the record in the course table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown your save code, it's hard to know. But you are probably adding existing objects to the context, but the context believes they are new.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I have filled the `UserCourse` Collection in the `Course` entity with the `User` reference object and the `Id` of the user. It works now without the reference object. I now only give the collection the `Id` of the reference object and EF now seems to get this resolved.